# Spring MVC - Reference Data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is the scenario: I have something like this..

```
<form:select path="somePath" .....>
   <form:option value="" label="Please Select"/>
   <form:options items="${students}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

This dropdown list works fine.

But how can I display name of a particular student? I wan to do something like this:

```
 <c:out value="${students[id].name}"/>
```

Can any one help me with the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the student name in response to a selection in you select?

Comment: Yes, its something like that., actually I am displaying all the students as a grid with edit link on each row. So when someone wants to edit a particular student (change name), they will click edit. A textbox on the page shows the name of that particular student, so that they can change the name and click on update button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `${students}` is an array or list of student objects.  As such, it's not indexed by id and can't be directly accessed that way.

Options include:

1) Include your collection of students as a map from id to student object; your `items` attribute then becomes `${students.values}`, and you can then look up an individual student as `${students[id]}`.

2) Or, keep it as a list and then iterate through your list and find the one where the id matches:

```
 <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
    <c:if test="${student.id==id}">
        <c:out value="${student.name}" />
    </c:if>
 </c:forEach>
```

3) Or, lastly, if you know from the beginning which student you care about, include that student separately in the reference data.

Comment: Thanks Jacob., its working... The ${students} is a map which has list of students as its values so I used the second option.